# Listview сбрасывает значение после повторного открытия диалогового окна

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-alertdialog

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку +, открывается диалоговое окно и там я ввожу название папки, и оно появляется в listview, а когда нажимаю ещё раз на + и ввожу, оно появляется вместо предыдущего названия

```
        ListView listView_language;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    Dialog dialog;
    MaterialButton showButton;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.p_lang);
        showButton = findViewById(R.id.showButton);
        dialog = new Dialog(p_lang.this);
        showButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomDialog();
            }
        });
    }
    private void showCustomDialog() {
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_1);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        MaterialButton next_button_1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_d);
        EditText editText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.plain_text);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        dialog.show();

        listView_language = findViewById(R.id.list_language);
        list=new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_view_layout_1,list);

        next_button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                listView_language.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                list.add(name);
                 arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Видимо неправильно реализован метод arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит потому что при каждом показе диалога пересоздаётся адаптер и связанный с ним список, а старый список с предыдущим значением теряется.
Адаптер следует создать однажды и потом только обновлять.

```java
    ListView listView_language;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    Dialog dialog;
    MaterialButton showButton;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.p_lang);
        showButton = findViewById(R.id.showButton);

        listView_language = findViewById(R.id.list_language);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_view_layout_1, list);

        dialog = new Dialog(p_lang.this);
        showButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomDialog();
            }
        });
    }
    private void showCustomDialog() {
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_1);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        MaterialButton next_button_1 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_d);
        EditText editText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.plain_text);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        dialog.show();

        next_button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                list.add(name);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```